# Start a function at a specified date

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I m working on a TV player on raspberry pi/raspbian

The player part work, my playlist work too, but I m stuck at this:

I get the playlist with a start date (parsing is ok), but I have no idea how I could do to replace the previous playlist by the new one at the scheduled date.

Is there a way to start a function only at a specified time without eating all the cpu by a false "wait"?

I was wondering about setTimeOut function, but is there better way than this?

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) or a callback which is called when the current playlist ends

Comment: Thanks, it will be setTimeout so, since the playlist only end when another one start, and there s no regular time.

Comment: Post your comment as answer if you want me to validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron).  It will make a call to your callback at the specified cron time.  Take a look at some sample code:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new cronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function(){
    // Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
    // at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
    // or Sunday.
    console.log('Hello');
}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```